# How to put tag my duplicate values in particular way

Tags: python, pandas

I have below .csv. I am trying to make a dataframe where I can find the duplicates and I need to find one more column where first value will be always

```
Name = [('Hello'),
      ('Spider'),
      ('Captain'),
      ('Superman'),
       ('Hello'),
       ('Superman')]
dfName = pd.DataFrame(Name, columns=['Name'])
dfNamedup = dfName[dfName.duplicated()]
#dfName

dfName['un_dup_hel'] = np.where(dfName['Name'].duplicated(keep=False),'duplicate', 'unique')

My out

Name    un_dup_hel
0   Hello   duplicate
1   Spider  unique
2   Captain unique
3   Superman    duplicate
4   Hello   duplicate
5   Superman    duplicate
```

For the first time my value will be unique, if it repeats then only it will show duplicates

Expected out. You can see that all the when `Hello and Superman` repeats then only I need to put as duplicates

```
Name    un_dup_hel
0   Hello   unique
1   Spider  unique
2   Captain unique
3   Superman    unique
4   Hello   duplicate
5   Superman    duplicate
```

Comment: Get rid of `keep=False` inside `duplicated`. The default `keep='first'` is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `keep=False` for default `keep='first'` parameter:

```
dfName['un_dup_hel'] = np.where(dfName['Name'].duplicated(),'duplicate', 'unique')

print (dfName)
       Name un_dup_hel
0     Hello     unique
1    Spider     unique
2   Captain     unique
3  Superman     unique
4     Hello  duplicate
5  Superman  duplicate
```

**Detail**:

```
print (dfName['Name'].duplicated())
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: Name, dtype: bool
```